# How do I skip an iteration in a for loop if its execution takes longer than X seconds?

Tags: python, for-loop, runtime, break

I have a for loop which loops over a bunch of functions inside the loop, something like this:

```
for i in [i_1, i_2, i_3, ...]:
    do_something(i)
    do_something_else(i)
    ...
```

I want to be able to skip the iteration for `i` if the total runtime inside the loop exceeds `x` seconds. An easy fix would be to add intermediate runtime checks after each function, something like this:

```
for i in [i_1, i_2, i_3, ...]:
    start_time = time.time()

    do_something(i)
    check_time = time.time()-start_time
    if check_time > x: 
       break

    do_something_else(i)
    check_time = time.time()-start_time
    if check_time > x: 
       break
    ...
```

Probably easiest to do in a function that I repeat after every step. However, I don't want to specify it after every single line in the code. Instead, I want to keep continuous track of the runtime inside the for loop, regardless of where it is in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something using the [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function which allows you to hook into the execution of lines of code and functions within the interpreter and check the total execution time whenever a function `return`s.

Here's a demonstration of the feasibility of the approach:

```
import sys
import time


class Timelimit:
    class TakingTooLong(Exception):
        def __init__(self, limit):
            self.limit = limit
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.limit} sec execution time limit exceeded'

    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        sys.settrace(self._trace)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.settrace(None)

    def _trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'opcode':
            return
        if event == 'return':
            elasped = time.time() - self.start_time
            #print(f'{elasped=:.4f}')
            if elasped > self.limit:
                raise self.TakingTooLong(self.limit)
            return
        if event != 'call':
            return

        func_name = frame.f_code.co_name  # Name of function being called.
        if func_name == 'write':
            return  # Ignore write() calls from printing
        #print('* Call to', func_name)
        return self._trace


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def do_something(i):
        print(f'do_something({i})')
        time.sleep(1)

    def do_something_else(i):
        print(f'do_something_else({i})')
        time.sleep(3)

    with Timelimit(10):
        try:
            for i in range(1, 5):
                do_something(i)
                do_something_else(i)
                ...
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f'---> Exception: {type(exc).__name__} - {exc}')
```

Results printed:

```
do_something(1)
do_something_else(1)
do_something(2)
do_something_else(2)
do_something(3)
do_something_else(3)
---> Exception: TakingTooLong - 10 sec execution time limit exceeded
```